# Proof/derivation of $e=\lim _{k\rightarrow 0}\left( 1+k\right)^{\frac{1}{k}}$

Tags: calculus

I was experimenting with some Recurrence relations and came to this one:

\begin{aligned}f\left( x+k\right) =\left( k+1\right) \cdot f\left( x\right)\end{aligned}

From there I went:

\begin{aligned}\\ f\left( x+k\right) -f\left( x\right) =kf\left( x\right) \end{aligned}

\begin{aligned}\\\dfrac{f\left( x+k\right) -f\left( x\right) }{k}=f\left( x\right)\end{aligned}

let k goes to zero
\begin{aligned} \\ \lim _{k\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{f\left( x+k\right) -f\left( x\right) }{k}=\dfrac{df\left( x\right) }{dx} =f\left( x\right)\end{aligned}

we know that:

\begin{aligned}\dfrac{df\left( x\right) }{dx}=f\left( x\right) =e^{x} \end{aligned}

lets insert our result into the first equation and we have:

\begin{aligned}\lim _{k\rightarrow 0}e^{\left( x+k\right) }=\lim _{k\rightarrow 0}ke^{x}+e^{x}\\ e^{x}\lim _{k\cdot \rightarrow 0}\left( e^{k}-k-1\right) =0\\ e=\lim _{k\rightarrow 0}\left( 1+k\right) ^{\dfrac{1}{k}}\end{aligned}

My question is this valid proof/derivation ? If yes, is it avaible anywhere ( I could not find it) and how is first equation related to: \begin{aligned} f\left( x\right) =e^{x} \end{aligned}

Comment: How do you know that $\frac{d}{dx} f(x) = f(x)$ has solution $f(x) = e^{x}$ without first knowing the limit definition of $e$?

Comment: @DMcMor we know that for some base of exponential function and we call it e we have $ f\left( x\right) =\dfrac{df\left( x\right) }{dx} $ we do not need to know its value .

Comment: What if $ f=0$?

Comment: As this is a recurrence relation,, so, how do take the limit $k\to 0 $ ?

Comment: How do $e^{x}$ satisfy $f(x+k)=(k+1)f(x)$?

Comment: How do you justify $e^k-(1+k)\to0$ implies $e-(1+k)^{1/k}\to0$? For example, $\frac{1}{k^k}-1\to0$ but $\frac{1}{k}-1\to\infty$.

Comment: Is $f(x+k)=( k+1) \cdot f(x)$ supposed to hold for all $x$ and $k$? If so, then $f(x+2)=3f(x)$ and $f(x+2)=2f(x+1)=4f(x)$ would mean that $f(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 2):

I'll address the second part of your question: How is the first equation related to $e^x$?

The "explicit" solution of $$f(x+k) = (k+1) \cdot f(x)$$

would be $f(x) = (k+1)^{\left\lfloor \frac{x}{k}\right\rfloor} \cdot f(x \mod k)$

Since you are taking the limit as $k \to 0$:  $$f(x) = \lim_{k \to 0} \left((k+1)^{\left\lfloor \frac{x}{k}\right\rfloor} \cdot f(x \mod k)\right)$$

Assuming that both terms converge as $k \to 0$, this can be split as $$f(x) = \lim_{k \to 0} (k+1)^{\left\lfloor \frac{x}{k}\right\rfloor} \cdot \lim_{k \to 0} f(x \mod k)$$

Assuming that $f(x)$ is continuous at $0$, this is equal to $$f(x) = f(0) \cdot \lim_{k \to 0}(k+1)^{\left\lfloor \frac{x}{k}\right\rfloor}$$

From here, you can sandwich the limit between $\left(k+1\right)^{\frac{x}{k}-1} \to e^x$ and $\left(k+1\right)^{\frac{x}{k}} \to e^x$ to show that $$f(x) = f(0) \cdot e^x = Ce^x$$